# Could our new plumbing be to blame for our new downstairs toilet and upstairs spare bath being clogged?

Tags: plumbing, troubleshooting

We need help troubleshooting our plumbing problem before we spend any more money on this house. We just spent quite a bit of money finishing our basement, where we added two bedrooms and a new full bathroom with two sinks and a shower for our children. We have never had plumbing issues before. We have a septic system. The  plumber had to jackhammer floor and change out pipes for this addition. Our upstairs has 2 full baths, but only the hall bath toilet is clogged. Sink drains fine. Then downstairs the toilet is also clogged. The sinks drain fine down there too,but the toilet gurgles when the water in sink is run and the pipe in shower drain has standing water in it! We have just our master bath toilet in working order! Any help and insight would be great. Ive looked up several things to try, but think this could be an issue caused by the new plumbing installed

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a clogged drain pipe or vent stack to me. Some toilet paper doesn't break down as well; such as charmin. I would switch to Scotts which breaks down rapidly.

Comment: why though does everything else associated with plumbing still work. We are not having any trouble with the master bath, kitchen sink, washing clothes or running water through the sinks in those bathrooms with clogged toilets. Do you think it is possible for us to get into the pipes to clear them without having to call an expensive plumber?

Comment: There are multiple drains that lead to the main drain, one of them is probably clogged.

You could get a drain snake and give that a try. You can buy ones that attach to a standard drill for like $20. Some are hand cranked. Search youtube on how to use them.